# Linq Transpose List

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of simple objects:

```
 var r = new  List
        {
            new { Id = 1, Value = 2, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("10.10.2014")},
            new { Id = 2, Value = 3, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("10.10.2014")},
            new { Id = 3, Value = 4, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("10.10.2014")},
            new { Id = 1, Value = 5, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("11.10.2014")},
            new { Id = 2, Value = 6, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("11.10.2014")}
        };
```

I want to get object like:

```
DateTime    | 1 | 2 | 3 |
10.10.2014  | 2 | 3 | 4 |
11.10.2014  | 5 | 6 |   |
```

Is there any nice linq query to this? Smth like pivot/unpivot in sql maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a simple `GroupBy`:

```
var result = r.GroupBy(x => x.DateTime)
              .Select (grp => new
               {
                   DateTime = grp.Key,
                   _1 = grp.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Int32?>().FirstOrDefault(),
                   _2 = grp.Where(x => x.Id == 2).Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Int32?>().FirstOrDefault(),
                   _3 = grp.Where(x => x.Id == 3).Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Int32?>().FirstOrDefault()
               });
```

`result` is now:

[image]

Comment: I think I prefer to use `.Select(x => new Nullable<int>(x.Value)` than `.Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Int32?>()` simply because its more type safe.

Comment: @sloth Out of the scope of this answer; Seeing the attached image, it prompted me to ask what tool did you use to build the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
r.ToLookup(t => t.id, t=>t.DateTime)
```

And if that doesn't work, read through [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/24/c.net-little-wonders-the-tolookup-linq-extension-method.aspx)

You are looking to group the list according to id and then key the resulting list by dictionary.  You should be able to do that with some combination of GroupBy, which creates a list of grouped lists and ToDictionary(), which creates allows you to specify a property of the object as a key and creates a dictionary from it.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of Ids are not known at compile-time then there is no way to create a link statement to capture those Ids as new fields. Linq just can do that. The best you can do in that case is this:

```
var ids = r.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

var query =
    from x in r
    group x by x.DateTime into gxs
    let lookup = gxs.ToLookup(x => x.Id, x => (int?)x.Value)
    select new
    {
        DateTime = gxs.Key,
        Values = ids.Select(i => new
        {
            Id = i,
            Value = lookup[i].FirstOrDefault(),
        }).ToArray(),
    };
```

That produces this:

[image: result]

If the Ids are known then the following variation is the best:

```
var query =
    from x in r
    group x by x.DateTime into gxs
    let lookup = gxs.ToLookup(x => x.Id, x => (int?)x.Value)
    select new
    {
        DateTime = gxs.Key,
        _1 = lookup[1].FirstOrDefault(),
        _2 = lookup[2].FirstOrDefault(),
        _3 = lookup[3].FirstOrDefault(),
    };
```

Comment: Hi, @Enigmativity, where is this screenshot from?

Comment: @NikolayKostov - I use http://www.linqpad.net/ for running my code and I create screenshots from its output.

Comment: It can be done with Dynamic Linq at runtime.  I managed to use it to query for an unknown number of search terms on an unknown number of fields (just like in this example... a vertical list of fields associated with each user that must be transposed in the result set), returning an unknown set of fields and ordering on an unknown set of fields.  A general multi-term over multi-field search.  System.Linq.Dynamic.